# What governs the decision to use server object model or client object model or javascript object model or REST?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, rest, client-object-model

What governs the decision to use (in SharePoint 2013)?:

1. server object model (ssom)
2. client object model (csom)
3. JavaScript object model (jsom)
4. REST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the following factors:

1. Server side object model : If your code runs on same machine as your Sharepoint farm. You should use Server side object model.
   The assemblies that define the built-in server-side classes are installed to the global assembly cache of each server when SharePoint 2013 is installed. When you program against the server object model, your assemblies are installed as farm solutions to the global assembly cache.
2. Client Object model: If you are accessing sharepoint data from any machine other than sharepoint server, you can use .Net managed client object model.
3. Javascript object model: If you want to access sharepoint data from Javascript code you should use JSOM.
4. REST : For scenarios in which you need to access SharePoint entities from client technologies that do not use JavaScript and are not built on the .NET Framework or Silverlight platforms, SharePoint 2013 provides an implementation of a Representational State Transfer (REST) web service that uses the OData protocol to perform CRUD operations on SharePoint list data

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060(v=office.15).aspx